Unable to get textcontent of an element using page.evaluate
I am updating firstname and trying to verify it . I am unable to see the updated firstname in DOM but it is visible in UI. Below is the code I am using
var updatedFirstName = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('[data-placeholder = "First Name"]').textContent)
console.log('updated firstname is ' +updatedFirstName)
I am receiving empty in place of +updatedFirstName in console.

Please share a [mcve] including your complete code and the page you're automating. '[data-placeholder = "First Name"]' is usually written as '[data-placeholder="First Name"]'. Otherwise, this looks basically correct and should work. If it doesn't work, it's due to page-specific dynamic behavior like an iframe, JS timing, shadow DOM, cloudflare block, race condition, etc, none of which can be assessed without seeing the actual site.

Thanks ggorlen. I am able to resolve this . In place of 'text Content' I used 'value'.  I realized that the DOM doesn't have text . It is only in UI. Sorry, I should have shared the DOM .
